# How to populate an array from a DataSet in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, dataset

I'm trying to populate an array from a dataset with only a specific column using VB.NET 2010. Is there any code to populate the array directly or must I make use of a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

Assuming you want an array of String:

```
Dim arr As String() = (From myRow In ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
                       Select myRow.Field(Of String)("yourColumnName")).ToArray
```

or a list:

```
Dim list As List(Of String) = (From myRow In ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
                               Select myRow.Field(Of String)("yourColumnName")).ToList
```

---

**Old**:

Make sure the DisplayMember is set to the name of the column you want to see:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
comboBox1.DisplayMember= "NameOfColumn"
```

You might also want to set the ValueMember property to the ID field name from your dataset.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake >.< | i have an array to fill and not a combobox.

Comment: No worries. I'll change my answer in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet

objDataSet = DataSetConsultas("SELECT Nombres, IDTarjeta from Alumnos")

Dim arr As String() = (From myRow In objDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
                    Select myRow.Field(Of String)("Nombres")).ToArray

cboAlumnos.Items.Clear()
cboAlumnos.Items.AddRange(arr)
```

Where `Nombres`, `IDTarjeta` are rows in the DB, and `Alumnos` is the name of the table