# Generate an array from dataset Vb.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, dataset, interop

I am looking for a way to generate a string array from a dataset column. I have came across few examples as below in C# but couldn't write a VB.Net equivalent using LINQ. I do not want to use loop to achive the same.

```
string[] columnNames = (from dc in ds.Tables(0).Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Though my final objective is to pass these value to Interop Assembly Worksheet.Range().

Comment: What problems have you found? The conversion is not too difficult; even an automatic language conversor can perform it.

Comment: Note: A linq query is just doing a loop "under the hood"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate an array from a DataSet in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430964/how-to-populate-an-array-from-a-dataset-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work in your case:

```
Dim arr As String() = (From myRow In ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable 
                      Select myRow.Field(Of String)("yourColumnName")).ToArray
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier. Somehow I couldn't get Toarray to work on rowcollection returned by LINQ. I am getting this error *ToArray is not a member of System.Data.Enumerablerowcollection(of String)*

Comment: @Nilanjan Just for clarification, did you add `Imports System.Linq` to your file?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't import System.Linq

Answer (score 1):

The VB equivalent is

```
Dim arr = (From dc In ds.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn) Select dc.ColumnName) _
          .ToArray()
```